# Looseness of the definition of domain adaption

Tags: computer-vision, domain-adaptation

I am a bit intrigued about “domain shift” concept. Specifically, in part 5 of the paper “Coupled Generative Adversarial Networks”, it reads

> We studied the problem of adapting a digit classifier from the MNIST dataset to the USPS dataset. Due to domain shift, a classifier trained using one dataset achieves poor performance in the other.

My understanding of domain shift is that there are different data generating processes. Since there are different people that contribute to a dataset, one can split a dataset and says his model suffer because of domain shift, not overfit. What is wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

If the data consists of i.i.d. samples, then splitting it randomly into training / validation / test won't change that (each subset still contains i.i.d. points). In this case, there is no domain shift. If your model does worse than expected on the test set, it's likely because your validation metrics were not an unbiased measure of the model, and you've overfit.

If different people contribute to a dataset, and you split train/test not randomly but by contributor, then the samples are no longer i.i.d., and the train distribution is different from the test distribution, so there is a domain shift. Here, your validation results could be an unbiased estimate of the model performance *on the distribution of the train/val data*, and if you still do worse on the test data, it's because the performance on the test distribution is different from that on the train distribution. Of course this doesn't rule out that you can overfit and suffer from domain shift at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you saying that since MNIST and USPS are from different contributors, domain shift is bounded to happen if one trains on MNIST and tests on USPS?

Comment: MNIST and USPS are definitely different distributions, so yes it would qualify as "domain shift".

Comment: Suppose I made sure they are the same size and used same normalization (`/255`), let's say, before feeding to a neural network. Could you elaborate then how different are they?